# a script with two different behavior on the same version of chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm not familiar with javascript but my boss would like me to solve something weird so I took some time to investigate, with no satisfaying answer so far. Problem is, we have a script (jQuery) which works perfectly on most of our computers except for two of them, on chrome exclusively. All with the exact same version of the browser (55.0.2883.87 m). The script is a slider (Flipster) with 4 slides, with 3 hidden on the faulty machines instead of 4 with one bigger on focus when everything goes according to plan. Anyway, you obviously won't be able to find the answer for me (and I don't ask for it) but what I may ask you is where I might start digging, if some of you ever faced such situation and found their way through this in some particular areas...
Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Forgot to say hi! :/

Comment: Question is too vague. Neither there is any code.

Comment: Empty cache/cookies/etc + run in incognito mode, there could be something in cache/cookies that is messing around with your code

Comment: make sure you're testing with the same user to make certain the dynamic content is the same (if any). make sure the browser size is the same if that matters. make sure you you clear the cache on all machines to start fresh if there has been recent development. make sure you kill any browser extensions in case those are causing trouble. For the record, this is not the correct type of question for this forum, but i hope that helps.

Comment: You can start by checking the console for errors in the chrome Dev tools. Alsof, try opening the Page in incognito mode, so you aren't dealing with cache

Comment: Thank you for all your answers , I really appreciate. And I sincerely apologize for the clumsiness of my question, and the description I made of  the problem. I'm not a native English speaker nor a seasoned dev and had not the slightest clue so I had to start somewhere, somehow. Now I'm gonna try your suggestions acontel, tommybananas and Jan_dh. Tanks again, and have a good day/evening